# How are these two groovy calls identical?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to understand how to invoke a groovy method defined as:

`Number.upto(Number to, Closure closure)`

It seems that very same method can be invoked in following two ways:

```
1.upto(10, {item -> println(item)})

1.upto(10) {item -> println item}
```

The first method call takes a `number` as first argument and a `closure` as second argument. This  matches the method definition. The second method call however takes only one argument which happens to be a number.

How is the second method call working?

Comment: Because that’s how Groovy was designed. If the last parameter is a closure it can be passed outside the parameter list.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks a bunch! So only if the  last parameter is a closure can this be done.

Comment: you can also omit brackets: `1.upto 10, {item -> println item}`, or even shorter `1.upto 10, this.&println`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is the second method call working?

```
1.upto(10) {item -> println item}
```

That method call works because the `upto` method accepts 2 parameters.  The first parameter is a `Number` and the second parameter is a `Closure`.  When passing a `Closure` literal as the final parameter to a method, Groovy allows the `Closure` literal to be defined outside of the parens for readability.

The following are identical...

```
def someClosure = { ... }
4.times(someClosure)

4.times {
    ...
}

4.times({ 
    ... 
})

4.times() {
    ...
}
```